# Finding distance and attributes from one feature to another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, road, parcel

My goal is to have a final parcel layer include fields containing road name and distance to the nearest road segment. I'm using ArcMap and tried running the Near tool but it only returns distances.

How can I obtain both the road name and the distance from parcel polygon to road?

Comment: Explore the spatial join tool.

Comment: I think you should investigate Near more because it should provide a NEAR_FID to join to your road fields that include nsme.